# Call to undefined function message in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently following a book tutorial on how to create a log in system using MySQL and php however I get the following error message after trying to choose a county (you can see the error message for yourself if you go to [cs12jkk.icsnewmedia.net](http://cs12jkk.icsnewmedia.net) then click on

**RegistrationPage.php:**

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_valid_county() in /home/cs12jkk/public_html/register-process.php on line 34
```

//here is line 34 on my **register process page:**

```
if (isset($_POST['county']) && $_POST['county'] != "") {
    if(!is_valid_county($_POST['county'])) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = "Please choose a valid county";
    }
}
```

here is my function in the **validation.inc page**

```
function is_valid_county($county) {
    $validCounties = array ( "Avon","Bedfordshire","Berkshire","Borders","Buckinghamshire","Cambridgeshire","Central","Cheshire","Cleveland","Clwyd","Cornwall","County Antrim","County Armagh","County Down","County Fermanagh","County Londonderry","County Tyrone","Cumbria","Derbyshire","Devon","Dorset","Dumfries and Galloway","Durham","Dyfed","East Sussex","Essex","Fife","Gloucestershire","Grampian","Greater Manchester","Gwent","Gwynedd County","Hampshire","Herefordshire","Hertfordshire","Highlands and Islands","Humberside","Isle of Wight","Kent","Lancashire","Leicestershire","Lincolnshire","Lothian","Merseyside","Mid Glamorgan","Norfolk","North Yorkshire","Northamptonshire","Northumberland","Nottinghamshire","Oxfordshire","Powys","Rutland","Shropshire","Somerset","South Glamorgan","South Yorkshire","Staffordshire","Strathclyde","Suffolk","Surrey","Teesside","Tyne and Wear","Warwickshire","West Glamorgan","West Midlands","West Sussex","West Yorkshire","Wiltshire","Worcestershire",);
    if (in_array($county,$validCounties)) {
            return true;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
} //end function is_valid_county
```

Comment: Do u have `is_valid_county()` in same page? Else the error will pop up

Comment: no where should I add that in?

Comment: where you put your `is_valid_country()` function ? this fatal error show that this function is not available in your page. have you included that file where you put this function?

Comment: my is_valid_county function is in my linked validation.inc page i've edited my question and put in the code ^

Comment: @user3196072 so include that page in your registration page

Comment: @user3196072 your validation.inc is not a php file when i see the link given by you. please add extension .php after this and then include it.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your code, is_valid_county method should be on same page:

```
if (isset($_POST['county']) && $_POST['county'] != "") {
    if(!is_valid_county($_POST['county'])) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = "Please choose a valid county";
    }
}

function is_valid_county($county) {
    // your code here
}
```

Later, as you edited your code, your function is in validation.inc
So, you need to include it here on the page:

```
include_once("validation.inc.php");

if (isset($_POST['county']) && $_POST['county'] != "") {
    if(!is_valid_county($_POST['county'])) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = "Please choose a valid county";
    }
}
```

Comment: stop copy paste of others answer

Comment: If you see, I have answered before you. Check the time.

Comment: yes but the edited answer and put my code now to your code. it seems bro.

Comment: Yes, I edited just to have .php extension on include.

Comment: do you think it has anything to do with me saying counties and county?

Comment: @user3196072 rename your file validation.inc to validation.inc.php ,  make sure you have code inside your <?php ?>  tags in validation.inc.php , include this validation.inc.php file on the top in your register-process.php

Answer (score -1):

first include validation.inc page in your registration page like this and then put your code

```
include_once("validation.inc.php");

if (isset($_POST['county']) && $_POST['county'] != "") {
    if(!is_valid_county($_POST['county'])) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = "Please choose a valid county";
    }
}
```

Comment: i've tried this and the error message is still there, do you mean my RegistrationPage or my register-process page?

Comment: that means you are not giving the correct path of `validation.inc.php`

Comment: show me your folder structure where is your file validation.inc.php and where is registration_process file.

Comment: @user3196072 your validation.inc is not a php file when i see the link given by you. please add extension .php after this and then include it.

Comment: it can be seen on the server at cs12jkk.icsnewmedia.net but my the path of the file is: /Users/jordanking48/Desktop/FinalApplicationDWP/ApplicationDWP/public_html

Comment: yes that ok see your file `validation.inc`. this is not a php file it has no php extension so please save it with `validation.inc.php`.

Comment: I've changed it and now get this 
Warning: include_once(validation.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cs12jkk/public_html/register-process.php on line 4

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'validation.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/cs12jkk/public_html/register-process.php on line 4

Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_valid_county() in /home/cs12jkk/public_html/register-process.php on line 35

Comment: bro thats i want to saying that there is no file `validation.inc.php'

Comment: ok do one more thing make another file `functions.php` and put your function `is_valid_country` there. and include functions.php in each your `reagistration page` as follows `include("functions.php");` for your easier i am posting another answer.

Comment: @user3196072 look at your `functions.inc` it has also no php extension and check the code of this file it also including the `validation.inc` not `validation.inc.php` change it also.